# Wordpress export to csv not downloading

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I have to export data from a table.On clicking "export CSV" button i need to download csv file.I want to display the output data as a table in the same page so i am unable to write action for csv export in another file.I have written export csv code on the same file.It outputs as values seperated with commas but not downloading csv.Here is my code

```
global $wpdb;

$id = $_POST['id'];

$timesheet_entry = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id" );

foreach($timesheet_entry as $entry){

        $csv_export.= $entry->id.",";
        $csv_export.= $entry->entry_date.",";
        $csv_export.= $entry->user_id.",";
        $csv_export.= $entry->hours_worked.",";
        $csv_export.= $entry->project_id.",";

        $csv_export.= '
';  
    }

$csv_filename ='export.csv';
// Export the data and prompt a csv file for download
header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$csv_filename."");

echo($csv_export);
```

Comment: Just to make it clear, is it a browser specific problem? Did you try downloading it on different browsers?

Comment: no error messages @Zameer Khan

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this code

```
header("Content-type: application/CSV");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=" . $csv_filename);
echo $csv_export;
```

Comment: If i put export csv code in another file it is working fine but it is not working in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments for the same page use:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
if( ! empty($id) ) {
    // Rest Code here
    // ..............

    exit();
}
```

This way help you to implement download CSV on the same page.